# Maximizing triangle area problem

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

Given the circumference of a circle having equation $$ x^2+y^2-4x-8y+16=0 $$ consider a straight line that passes through the origin and intersects the circumference at the points $P$ and $Q$. Find the slope so that the area of the $APQ$ triangle is maximum. Point $A$ is $(0;4)$.

I know that I should use the derivative in order to determine the maximum area of the triangle, but I don't know how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Define you straight line with slope *m* as y=m*x. Look for the intersection of this straight line with your circle. For a circle, this will obviously result in a quadratic equation:

$$
x^{2} + m^{2}x^{2} + 16 - 4x -8mx = 0
$$

The discriminant is $64m-48$. Consequently

$$
x_{1,2} = \frac{4+8m \pm \sqrt{64m-48}}{2(1+m^{2})} \\
y_{1,2} = mx_{1,2} \\
x_{3} = 0 \quad y_{3} =4
$$

The area of a simple polygon based on its coordinates can most easily be found by using the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula):
$$
\frac{1}{2}∣x_{1}y_{2}+x_{2}y_{3}+x_{3}y_{1}−x_{1}y_{3}−x_{3}y_{2}−x_{2}y_{1}∣
$$

this will be a formula in function of m. Differentiate and set equal to zero.

Good luck!

*fixed typo

Comment: The area of the triangle equals $OAQ - OAP.  (O$ is the origin).  Since OA is on the $y$ axis (and 4 units long), the area $2(x_1 -x_2)$

Comment: Great improvement, @doug-m M!

Comment: Degenerate? If $C(2,4) $ is center of circle , $ CO= CA= OA/2= 2  $ units. $C$ is mid pt of $OA$

Comment: Then  a line parallel to x-axis cuts at $Q, \rightarrow Q(2,2)$  Circle tangential to x-axis?

Answer (score 1):

Let $m$ be the slope of the line through the origin.  Find the coordinates of $P$ and $Q$ as a function of $m$, then find the area of the triangle as a function of $m$.  Differentiate, set to zero ....

Comment: Just a  hunch.. $\Delta APQ$ is equilateral (without calculation). Wrong?

Comment: @Narasimham Good guess, but it doesn’t look like it to me.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=mx$, then the perpendicular distance of $A$ from $PQ$ (i.e. $y=mx$) is

$$h=\frac{4}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$$

Now

\begin{align}
  0 &= (1+m^2)x^2-4(2m+1)x+16 \\
  (x_1-x_2)^2 &= (x_1+x_2)^2-4x_2x_2 \\
  &= \frac{16(2m+1)^2}{(1+m^2)^2}-\frac{4 \times 16}{1+m^2} \\
  &= \frac{16(4m-3)}{(1+m^2)^2} \\
  S &= \frac{h\times PQ}{2} \tag{area} \\
  &= 2\sqrt{\frac{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}{1+m^2}} \\
  &= 2\sqrt{\frac{(x_1-x_2)^2+m^2(x_1-x_2)^2}{1+m^2}} \\
  &= 2|x_1-x_2| \\
  &= \frac{8\sqrt{4m-3}}{1+m^2} \\
 \frac{dS}{dm} &=
 \frac{16}{(1+m^2)\sqrt{4m-3}}-\frac{16m\sqrt{4m-3}}{(1+m^2)^2} \\
  0 &= \frac{16(1+3m-3m^2)}{(1+m^2)^2\sqrt{4m-3}} \\
  m &= \frac{3+\sqrt{21}}{6} \tag{$m > \frac{4}{3}$} \\
\end{align}